# Species ID: Buckyball-like fungus

Tags: species-identification, mycology, mushroom

**Previous research**

- A friend of mine shared a link of some beautiful fungi: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B81Pu.jpg. I was intrigued by the curious critter below -- it seems to have honed the power of buckyball geometry, presumably much before we Humans ever did (search: *Buckminsterfullerene* to learn about a feat of chemical engineering).
- Google reverse-image search almost got me the answer I needed, but no species name.
- I've asked friends on Facebook with no answers yet.

---

**Question**

What is the name of this species of fungus?

[image]

---

**Related Questions on Stack Biology**

- Here's a related Species Identification question of a fungus: [Puffball mushroom species ID?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10738/puffball-mushroom-species-id) (by [@rg255](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/1590/rg255))

---

**EDIT**: I'm an idiot... the Imgur had species names, thus answering my question, *post-mortem*. Thanks [@skymningen](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/3827/skymningen) for pointing that out.

Comment: If you like the general idea of how wondrous mathematics in nature can be, read "What Shape is a Snowflake?" by Ian Stewart. It's a nice read, I loved it as a youth and I blame some of my fascination for biology to this book.

Comment: I understand the face palm, but it might be more useful to future readers if you change the title again.

Comment: @AtlLED, I'm not quite sure what you mean? As in to add the species name?

Comment: The question would appear as "answered", and @Ilan did technically answer it before I read the comments. I would suggest you voting to close my answer down, let the community decide.. I was about to delete it but then I read the deletion message

Comment: Sorry, I mean the top heading title not the question title.  The "Edit: I'm an idiot..." part is kind of jarring.  I don't think it needs to be deleted.  Maybe a more subtle note after the link?  Anyway, I guess this is more of a style point so feel free to ignore.

Comment: Almost same-looking: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/is-this-a-plant-or-a-fungus

Comment: @skymningen so so wonderful

Comment: @skymningen, I am intrigued: why did you use the word "blame"?

Comment: @hello_there_andy I am not a native english speaker. Connotations of words might be different in my native language. It was supposed to be a cheeky comment.

Comment: I see @skymningen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks very similar to [Clathrus ruber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrus_ruber) fungus.

Be careful, it is poisonous.

[image]

Comment: Actually... the link the OP gave has named pictures and it was also named as Clathus ruber there. So I guess you got it right.

Comment: @skymningen I didn't use the link in question. Hm, nice to know.

Comment: @skymningen thanks for pointing that out... I genuinely didn't notice those... \*facepalm\*... \*re-edits the question\*

Comment: @hello_there_andy Happens. Without that question I would have never known this interesting fungus!

Comment: Who knew fungi could be so... fun. Sorry that pun had to be done. @skymningen